# Select with Ctrl+Click on JS Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm making group of mailing addresses selection based on click on a map. I have found a ready to use solution. It is Russian Map with all the regions marked already. The regions change the color on `MouseOver` event which is good. Now I need to have those regions stay selected with Ctrl+Click and I can't seem to figure this out. Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/LxtMY/8/

I was trying to change `MouseOver` and `MouseOut` events to `event.CtrlKey` at the very bottom of the script:

```
F(Q).trigger("alwaysOn.maphilight").find("area[coords]").bind("mouseover.maphilight",X).bind("mouseout.maphilight",function(Z){L(T)});
U.before(T);
U.addClass("maphilighted")
```

but that produced no result. Maybe I'm editing a wrong thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `area` tag must have an unique id:

```
<area id="murmansk" ... />
```

Then add following JavaScript code:

```
$('area').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var id = e.currentTarget.id;
   var data = $('#' + id).mouseout().data('maphilight') || {};
   data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
   $('#' + id).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
});
```

You might use a style class instead of `area` as a selector if you're gonna have more than one map on your webpage.

Find another example here:

- http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_features.html

If you need to evaluate selected provinces/countries, then you might use jQuery maphilight (if they provide you such a method) or add/remove selected areas to an array in your JavaScript code.